# Can I call multiple methods from <p:ajax event=select listner=method1, metho2>?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

Can I call multiple methods from the ajax event select in listener?

```
<p:tree value="#{ddTreeBean.root}" var="node" dynamic="true"
                selectionMode="single" selection="#{ddTreeBean.selectedNode}">

<p:ajax event="select" listener="#{data2.refresh}"
                    update=":pchartId,:panelId">
                    </p:ajax>
        <p:treeNode type="node" expandedIcon="folder-open"
                    collapsedIcon="folder-collapsed">
                    <h:outputText value="#{node.name}" />
                </p:treeNode>

                <p:treeNode type="leaf" icon="document-node">
                    <h:outputText value="#{node.name}" />
                </p:treeNode>
            </p:tree>
```

on a select I need to bind my listener to two methods?
Is that allowed?

I have a tree and when I make a selection, I need to update (trigger) two components (two other back beans).
Does listener attribute take two parameters (two method names)?
THanks.

```
Myclass1 class {
 method1();
 }



Myclass2 class {
 method2();

 }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to call a method of one ManagedBean from another, you have to Inject the other ManagedBean.

```
@ManagedBean
public class MyBean1{

   public void methodAbc(){
     ...
   }
}
```

Inject in to

```
@ManagedBean
public class MyBean2{

   @ManagedProperty(value = "#{myBean1}")
   private MyBean1 mybean1;

   //SETTER GETTER for mybean1

   public void myAction(){
     mybean1.methodAbc();
   }
}
```

Compatible ManagedBean Injection scoped are given in following table(courtesy of Core Java Server Faces Book):
[image]

OR You can dynalically resolve EL expression in your Action method itself as follows.

```
public void myAction(){
   FacesContext fctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
   MyBean1 mybean1 = fctx.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(fctx , "#{myBean1}", MyBean1.class);
   mybean1.methodAbc();
}
```

Since you are using Primefaces there is one more way to do this, using `p:remoteCommand` :

```
<p:ajax event="select" listener="#{data2.refresh}"
        update=":pchartId,:panelId" 
        oncomplete="callRemote2()"/>

<p:remoteCommand name="callRemote" partialSubmit="true" process="@this" 
                 action="#{yourmanagedbean.method2}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't. You can have a single method where you call the two or more methods you need to execute:

```
<p:ajax event="select" listener="#{someMB.multipleMethods}" update=":pchartId,:panelId" />
```

And in Java side

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SomeMB {
    public void method1() { /* */ }
    public void method2() { /* */ }
    public void multipleMethods() { 
        method1();
        method2();
    }
}
```

If you need to use several managed beans, an option is to inject one into the other:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class AnotherMB {
    public void method2() { /* */ }
}

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SomeMB {

    @ManagedProperty("#{anotherMB}")
    AnotherMB anotherMB;

    //provide a setter
    public void setAnotherMB(AnotherMB anotherMB) {
        this.anotherMB = anotherMB;
    }

    public void method1() { /* */ }
    public void multipleMethods() { 
        method1();
        anotherMB.method2();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to call two methods in two different backing beans. public class MB1 {public void updateDisplay();} public class MB2 {public void updateChart();} Two methods are not on a same backing bean.

Comment: @user3482742 answer updated to show how to inject a bean into another. If you use CDI, this is way simpler.

Comment: That looks like it will work. I will give a try. Basically I have a primefaces tree with 2-4 components which receives the selection and update its component based on the selection. Thanks and I will get back to you if I could make this work.